# Html.EditorFor - How to use based on post parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

My ActionResult looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string engineer, string contactName, 
                          string company,  string searchKeyword)
{
```

It then returns a view based on a few LINQ queries running underneath, which use the passed in parameters (engiener, contactName etc) to determine the returned model.

I am generating a form in the view which acts as a form to post values to the controller as to filter the results. At the moment it looks like this - the code works fine and the search boxes work but this seems like bad practice and I can't add a class in to Html.Editor:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Contact Name")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Editor("contactName")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Keyword Search")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Editor("searchKeyword")
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to be able to use an EditorFor as that seems best practice but as the parameters are not in the model I am not sure how to reference them in the first part of the statement?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => what Do I put here!?)
```

Comment: So where are the 'parameters' then? You have to store them somewhere. Otherwise, just write plain old html.

Comment: They are passed into the actionresult string engineer, string contactName etc. Is the way I'm doing this not following common convention?

Comment: If you want to use EditorFor you have to show what model parameter is responsible for that editor. You don't have model class, so you cannot use  @Html.EditorFor. 
If you stil want to use EditorFor, LablelFor, DropDownFor etc, you have to create model class with all your properties and define and the top of page what type is your model class.

Comment: No. MVC is done using a Model, a View and a Controller, and they are not optional. You will only make your life easier if you add a model, the framework does a lot of heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I already have a model, in that I am using entity framework to generate the model I am passing to the view? What's the best way to modify that to get what I need, create a new model of which the entity model is a part of?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have those properties in the model, that's the point of this framework.

What you might not realize, though, is that the model you pass to the page (let's call it "view model") doesn't have to be the same as the one you store in the database (the "domain model"). The view model needs to have everything that the controller needs to pass from and to the view. The domain model needs to have everything that the controller needs to pass from and to the database.

While these may happen to be the same thing in trivial scenarios (like plain CRUD applications), if it doesn't work for you, don't hesitate to change them. Pass to the view a (new) kind of model that contains the parameters you need.

Comment: The model I have at the moment is currently being generated by entity framework. I assume I'd need to create a new model, of which the entity framework model was a part of?

Comment: The EF is your ORM, which takes care of managing the domain models. What you want to pass to your view is a view model, thus it doesn't need to involve the EF. You can just go ahead and define your own, custom, plain class and pass that as a view model - it doesn't need to have a table in the database or a set in the database context, or anything like that. You can even pass a string as the view model, as far as ASP.NET MVC is concerned.